# Sample from a tensor in Tensorflow along an axis

Tags: tensorflow

I have a matrix `L` of shape `(2,5,2)`. The values along the last axis form a probability distribution. I want to sample another matrix `S` of shape `(2, 5)` where each entry is one of the following integers: `0, 1`.
For example,

```
L = [[[0.1, 0.9],[0.2, 0.8],[0.3, 0.7],[0.5, 0.5],[0.6, 0.4]],
     [[0.5, 0.5],[0.9, 0.1],[0.7, 0.3],[0.9, 0.1],[0.1, 0.9]]]
```

One of the samples could be,

```
S = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

The distributions are binomial in the above example. However, in general, the last dimension of `L` can be any positive integer, so the distributions can be **multinomial**.

The samples need to be generated efficiently within Tensorflow computation graph. I know how to do this using numpy using the functions `apply_along_axis` and `numpy.random.multinomial`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`tf.multinomial()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multinomial) here.

You will first need to reshape your input tensor to shape `[-1, N]` (where `N` is the last dimension of `L`):

```py
# L has shape [2, 5, 2]
L = tf.constant([[[0.1, 0.9],[0.2, 0.8],[0.3, 0.7],[0.5, 0.5],[0.6, 0.4]],
                 [[0.5, 0.5],[0.9, 0.1],[0.7, 0.3],[0.9, 0.1],[0.1, 0.9]]])

dims = L.get_shape().as_list()
N = dims[-1]  # here N = 2

logits = tf.reshape(L, [-1, N])  # shape [10, 2]
```

---

Now we can apply the function `tf.multinomial()` to `logits`:

```py
samples = tf.multinomial(logits, 1)
# We reshape to match the initial shape minus the last dimension
res = tf.reshape(samples, dims[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Be cautious when using [tf.multinomial()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/multinomial). The inputs to the function should be logits and not probability distributions.
However, in your example, the last axis is a probability distribution.